# Changing the Style of different lines in PlotLabel

Tags: plotting

The following code renders a chart (shown further below). How can I achieve the styling descibed in the chart's title?

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLabel -> Style["The top line should be bold and black\n The bottom line should be a smaller font, black, and normal", Black, Bold]]
```

[image]

Comment: Try `Column[{Style["The top line should be bold and black", Black, Bold, 14], Style["The bottom line should be a smaller font, black, and normal", Black, 8]}, Center]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can [`StringJoin (<>)`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringJoin.html) styled strings wrapping each with `ToString[..., StandardForm]`:

```
label = ToString[Style["The top line should be bold and black",
     14, Bold, Black], StandardForm] <> 
  ToString[Style["\nThe bottom line should be a smaller font, black, and normal", 
     10, Black], StandardForm]
```

[image]

```
Plot[x^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotLabel -> label]
```

[image]